# DB2 LUW V10.5 on Windows. How to Manually rotate the Diaglog using scripts

Tags: db2, db2-luw

In DB2 LUW V10.5 on Windows, is there a way to manually rotate the diaglog log file? Currently, it is almost 1GB and it is difficult to open it to find info.The diagsize is set to 0 and I cannot change it due to other constraints.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to rotate the db2diag.log file is to use the `db2diag` utility with the `-A` ("archive") option.  It will rename the current db2diag.log file (appending the current timestamp to the file name).

`db2diag` is also quite useful for searching through huge db2diag.log files (instead of trying to open them in a text editor).  It has many options to filter the file based on time, content of messages, etc.  You can read more in [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0011728.html).